# Why will mouseenter fire the function, while you don't hover over an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code should only be called when the users mouse cursor enters the div element `.post-entry`. By now, when I just refresh the page, I immediately receive the console.log enter and move.

```
app.uiController = {

    init: function() {

        // Development
        console.log('init uiController');

        var el = $('.entry .post-entry');
        var dot = $('img');


        // Call functions
        $(el).on('mouseenter', app.uiController.mouseEnter());
        $(el).on('mousemove', app.uiController.mouseMove());

    }, 

    mouseEnter: function() {

        console.log('enter');

    }, 

    mouseMove: function() {

        console.log('move');


    }

}
```

app.uiController object will be called by the page by default. As mentioned before, mouse enter and move works immediately after the script is loaded, but I assigned the variable `el` to the event, so when the mouse position enters .post-entry it should do the linked function.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `()` will invoke the function... Pass `app.uiController.mouseMove` as argument...

Comment: @Rayon Just passing it as an argument may have `this` problems.

Comment: @gcampbell – OP never used `this` in the handler and passing and `this` context will not be lost by passing `function-name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rayon pointed out instead of passing

```
// Call functions
$(el).on('mouseenter', app.uiController.mouseEnter());
```

the following must be passed

```
// Call functions
$(el).on('mouseenter', app.uiController.mouseEnter);
```

This passes the function without executing it.

#### Update

You can use `this` inside `mouseEnter`: for example

```
mouseEnter: function() {
    id = $( this ).attr("id");
    $("#result").text('enter that.id =' + id);

}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get the current element passed to the function mouseEnter and mouseMove?